# Wrong amdgpu drivers installed and unable to uninstall it

Tags: linux-mint, apt, graphics, amd-graphics

I have linux mint, equivalent to ubuntu 16.04. I changed my graphic card and I uninstall the nvidia drivers to install the amd ones, but I installed drivers for ubuntu 18.04 instead of 16 and now I can't remove it, and I can't install or upgrade anything else.

When I type: # amdgpu-pro-uninstall

```
noik@noik-mint ~ $ amdgpu-pro-uninstall 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'amdgpu-core' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core (= 18.40-673869) but it is not going to be installed
 amdgpu-dkms : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 amdgpu-pro-core : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 glamor-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 gst-omx-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-amdgpu-common : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm2-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libgbm1-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libllvm6.0-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libllvm6.0-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libwayland-amdgpu-client0 : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libwayland-amdgpu-server0 : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I try with: # sudo apt-get -f install

```
noik@noik-mint ~ $ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 99 not upgraded.
64 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2.284 B of archives.
After this operation, 12,3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-core 18.40-673869 [2.284 B]
(Reading database ... 290174 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-core_18.40-673869_all.deb ...
ERROR: This package can only be installed on Ubuntu 16.04.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-core_18.40-673869_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-core_18.40-673869_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I type: sudo apt-get purge amd*
Or I type: sudo apt-get autoremove
The same result than amdgpu-pro-uninstall upgrade appears.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve it with commands, I solve it with Synaptic Package Manager, filtering by broken packages and "mark for complete removal".

Answer (score 0):

In my case uninstallation works with `sudo amdgpu-uninstall`.